# AWS Lambda pass data to another Lambda via alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a AWS Lambda that is running every minute.  It will either succeed or pass.  I have a AWS Alarm that is monitoring this Lambda and going into an ALERT or SUCCESS state based on the Lambda execution.  When the Alarm state changes a SNS message is fired off an another Lambda is triggered.  This Lambda uses a webhook and sends out a message.

Is there a way of getting the error message from the 1st Lambda to be viewed by the 2nd Lambda (and ultimatley passed to the webhook)? I can see the error message on the CloudWatch logs.

Any ideas on this would be great.

The reason I have a Alarm inbetween the 1st Lambda and the SNS is I only want a message when the state changes not every time the 1st Lambda runs.

Comment: put message or something like ID to SQS, then use Lambda #2 to get that info?

Comment: I need something to keep the old state. Otherwise I would just post from Lambda #1 to the webhook.

Comment: Seems like SQS would work here if what you want to do is catch the failure case of Lambda 1. Lambda 1 places error on SQS in event of failure. When when alarm state changes (due to error) the 2nd lambda is fired off and it reads from the SQS and passes result to webhook. Queue would be empty on success of Lambda 1 and only contain info if it fails.